# Kotlin - Inherit from Java Class that implements Parcelable

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin, just trying it out.

The first class from my project I converted to Kotlin has an inner class that extends RectF (which implements Parcelable).

`static class MyClass extends RectF`

converted to

`internal class MyClass : RectF()`

But has the following error:

> This class implements Parcelable but does not provide a CREATOR field

Experimenting, I found `val CREATOR = RectF.CREATOR` in MyClass removes the error, but this is ugly hack.

Can anyone explain/solve the issue here?

Many thanks.

Comment: Is it really an error or a warning? You should be getting the same warning from your Java code. Most likely you should have used composition and not inheritance from the start.

Comment: No warning in Java code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to comply to the [`Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) contract:

> Classes implementing the `Parcelable` interface must also have a non-null static field called `CREATOR` of a type that implements the `Parcelable.Creator` interface.

But your hack only removes the lint error. You should implement the `Parcelable.Creator` for your class directly, not re-use the one of `RectF`.

```
internal class MyClass : RectF() {
    companion object {
        @JvmField
        val CREATOR = Parcelable.Creator() { ... }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems strange though. The RectF class implements the Parcelable interface, and fulfils that contract. No issue in Java code.

Comment: You could also have a look at [PaperParcel](http://grandstaish.github.io/paperparcel/) to generate everything for you.

Comment: If you use the parent class CREATOR, then after deserializing you'll end up with an instance of the parent class, not the child class. You need to write a CREATOR for the child class as well.